# wordpress how to hide all post from search engine or not

Tags: php, wordpress, seo

i want to create a wordpress website but i have a Question. i will post regulary on it and any user can post after registration and
his post will show after admin's approve.

explain my question :

category : computer, medical, science
post : how to repair computer ? >> this post is show in computer category
ok

so i want to ask if i dont want to index my and post in google how can i do.
i want to make a new page like : computer.php and will display all computer category post on it with SEO. i will enable search engine for it. 
but i don't want to index any induvidiul post..

because some post is very short. and some post is only 2-3 lines.

and my some post's title can be same so i dont want to index any post i want to get all post in new worspress page and 
display with pegination.

tell me it's good idea ????

Answer (score 0):

You can use robots.txt to make google, bing... ignore your web pages depending on their url.
For example if your posts use urls like "www.yourdomain.com/posts/12-post-title" you can tell them to ignore all urls starting with "www.yourdomain.com/posts/" with just writing:

```
Disallow: /posts/
```

More info:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard